# GTM OAauth2: exchanging access code for access token

Tags: ios, google-api, oauth-2.0

I am using GTM OAuth2 library for authentication in my application based loosely on the following guide: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp.

I was able to retrieve an access code for a user, however, I am not sure how to swap this for an access token. I have searched through the documentation and have so far been unable to find any relevant examples. Is there a method in the library that supports this exchange?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean my "Access Code" is that password? Anyway, I've managed to get the GTM OAuth2 code working, including retrieving an accesstoken after the user has authenticated. I've made a simple project where you only need to put in your Client ID and Client Secret, maybe this can help you.

https://github.com/Christian-Hansen/simple-oauth2

Good luck.

Christian